# Insert a block in order email confirmation template

Tags: magento, email, templates, layout

I would like to insert a .phtml template block which contains some custom parameters associated to the order in the template structure of the order email confirmation sent to the customer.
I have tried introducing this in the corrsponding layout:

```
<sales_email_order_items>
<reference name="items">
<action method="unsetChildren"></action>
<block type="page/html_wrapper" name="email.order" translate="label">
<block type="email/order" name="email.order" template="custom/order.phtml" />
</block>
</reference>
</sales_email_order_items>
```

But, no way... any clue?

Answer (score 2):

You can call any block in directly in email template like this:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="newsletter_header"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the default coding, just add the custom variable in the email template,
Locate the template in  the following path,

```
Admin > System > transactional emails->Your_Template
```

Under ‘Template Information, enter a new variable name (very important to id your new email from the default one) and save the template.

Comment: Thanks for this tip KesaVan, the point is that I have a lot of backend variables that needs to be computed in php based on the checkout option selected, they are not frontend-admin-generated custom variables. I have the phtml file generated, and it needs to be inserted just after the items in the email template.